# How to bind Jquery dialog buttons to a knockout viewmodel

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

What I'd like to do is make a dialog where the buttons are databound to the knockout viewmodel  so I can enable or disable those buttons depending on various conditions on the form

But the way you make buttons in jquery dialogs is a bit different than normal.

anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure to apply your own `class` to the dialog's buttons:

   ```
   $("#dialog").dialog({
       buttons: [{
           text: 'Ok',
           class: 'ok-button'
       }]
   });
   ```
2. Grab the `button.ok-button` and apply a `data-bind` attribute to it (`visible` here, just to show you that it works). Here, `name` is an observable property of our view model:

   ```
   $("button.ok-button").attr("data-bind", "visible: name().length");
   ```
3. Apply bindings normally:

   ```
   var model = { name: ko.observable('') };
   ko.applyBindings(model);
   ```

Here's an example that hide's an "Ok" button on the dialog if `name` (an observable) has a length `> 0`: http://jsfiddle.net/9cRFy/

Comment: it does not work, however, with the `click` BindingHandler: http://jsfiddle.net/9cRFy/29/

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Andrew's answer, since the data-bind attribute is just another attribute you can add to your buttons, this would also work:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Ok',
        'data-bind': 'visible: name().length'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Hi @Greg Smith that is an awesome idea, but I couldn't get it to work using the click binding. Will this work for the other bindings?

Comment: Actually don't worry I used this with a mix of @ClayKaboom 's comment so adding a fake click: function() { } as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works when you call `applyBindings` *after* creating the dialog.