# knockout.js - How to bind disable property in jQuery uiDialog

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I use knockout and jQuery UI with [knockout-jquery-ui-widget.js](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets).

I create Dialog:

```
        <div class="dialog" id="my-dialog" data-bind='jqueryui: { widget: "dialog", options:{autoOpen: false,modal:true,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                width: 600,
                position: "center top+80",
                title:MyApp.i18n.gettext("Configure")
                } }'>
                ...
                </div>
```

and in my code I open it with:

```
$("#my-dialog").dialog("option", "buttons", that.getButtons()).dialog("open");
```

where

```
that.getButtons = function(){
  return [{
    text: MyApp.i18n.gettext("Button1"),
    click: function(){
       ...
    },
    disable: ?
   }];
};
```

My problem is, how to bind disable value to this jQuery UIButton in jQuery UIDialog.

Is there any posible to do that without write own template in html with own buttons?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question, I think this answers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801458/how-to-bind-jquery-dialog-buttons-to-a-knockout-viewmodel

Comment: Not exacly becouse I define my dialog as data-bind='jqueryui: {widget:"dialog"}'. But this solution is really good solution :)
Just before open I should add data-bind to this dialog (check if it's done only once) and everything should work.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea whether this would work as I've never used the jquery ui library but Knockout provides it's own [disable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html) binding

```
<div class="dialog" id="my-dialog" 
     data-bind='disable: amIDisabled, jqueryui: { ... }'>
            ...
</div>
```

Where `amIDisabled` is an observable in your view model

Comment: Yeah, but I need to pass disable option to one button in jQueryUI Dialog, not to whole dialog.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I think this is my lack of knowledge on how jquery ui library works.  Where do you define your `<button>` or `<label>` in html or is that dynamically generated?

Comment: I'd dynamically generate this buttons. In the worst case I can define it in HTML and then there will be no problem with data-bind